# what are the spring integration classes used stdin-channel-adapter?

Tags: java, spring-integration, messaging

I am interested to know the classes used in spring integration tag so that I can get more details of the tags by going through the javadoc of the classes.

I have two basic questions:

1. Do the spring integration xml tags (for example stdin-channel-adapter) convert to `<bean class=".." />` tags?
2. how to figure out the bean class associated with the spring integration tags?

Here is a simple example of spring integration xml context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream-4.0.xsd">


<int-stream:stdin-channel-adapter id="producer" channel="messageChannel" />
<int:poller id="defaultPoller" default="true" max-messages-per-poll="2" fixed-rate="100" />

<int-stream:stdout-channel-adapter id="consumer" channel="messageChannel" append-newline="true" /> 

<int:channel id="messageChannel" /> 

</beans>
```

Thanks

Comment: 1) *"Do tags convert to tags?"* Eh, what?!? --- 2) Run the code, then get the bean from the bean factory and see what it is. It's called [empirical evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_evidence) (knowledge acquired by means of observation).

Comment: 1) sorry it was formatting issue. I updated the question to give little bit more clarity.
2) Your solution is one way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have some mistake in your first question. See Andreas' comment.

Anyway the answer for you is like.

Any custom tags in Spring are handler by the particular `NamespaceHandler`. Typically you can find the target impl in file like `META-INF/spring.handlers` in the particular Spring jar, e.g.:

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream=org.springframework.integration.stream.config.StreamNamespaceHandler
```

With that in hands you can find the code like:

```
this.registerBeanDefinitionParser("stdin-channel-adapter", new ConsoleInboundChannelAdapterParser());
```

Where you can determine that a `ConsoleInboundChannelAdapterParser` is responsible for parsing and instantiation beans for `<stdin-channel-adapter>`  tag.

And there you can find the code like:

```
BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(
            "org.springframework.integration.stream.CharacterStreamReadingMessageSource");
```

So, the real class for target bean instance is `CharacterStreamReadingMessageSource`. But that's not all.

Please, look here for the design and model: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips

Comment: Excellent explanation and this is what I was looking for. Thanks.